# The platform "android" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. android not supported

Tags: ios, cordova, azure-devops

I am using VSTS for making IOS build, I am getting the following error after running the command : cordova build ios

The platform "android" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. android not supported.

Cordova version : 7.1.0

Running it on Macos agent. The same is working fine for android app but for IOS it giving the following error.

LOGS:

```
2018-01-08T08:47:31.4862230Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
2018-01-08T08:47:31.4883290Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PLATFORM
2018-01-08T08:47:31.4904030Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CONFIGURATION
2018-01-08T08:47:31.4925020Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CORDOVAVERSION
2018-01-08T08:47:31.4945860Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_ANTBUILD
2018-01-08T08:47:31.4966750Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_KEYSTOREFILE
2018-01-08T08:47:31.4987460Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_IOSSIGNMETHOD
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5009210Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_P12
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5030070Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_UNLOCKDEFAULTKEYCHAIN
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5050630Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PROVPROFILE
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5071250Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_REMOVEPROFILE
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5091830Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_WINDOWSPHONEONLY
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5112430Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_WINDOWSONLY
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5133220Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CWD
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5153800Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_OUTPUTPATTERN
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5175590Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TARGETEMULATOR
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5198350Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5219940Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5242140Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5264390Z ##[debug]loading SECRET_CODE-PUSH-ACCESS-KEY
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5285960Z ##[debug]loaded 19
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5307600Z ##[debug]BUILD_SOURCEDIRECTORY=undefined
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5329380Z ##[debug]BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY=/Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/13/s
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5351720Z ##[debug]CWD=/Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/13/s/dev-branch/src/Alcami.Web/cordova
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5372600Z ##[debug]XCODEDEVELOPERDIR=null
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5393140Z ##[debug]CONFIGURATION=$(Configuration)
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5413230Z ##[debug]ARCHS=null
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5433270Z ##[debug]PLATFORM=ios
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5453660Z ##[debug]TARGETEMULATOR=false
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5474170Z ##[debug]WINDOWSAPPX=null
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5494620Z ##[debug]WINDOWSONLY=false
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5517410Z ##[debug]WINDOWSPHONEONLY=false
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5539710Z ##[debug]UNLOCKDEFAULTKEYCHAIN=false
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5561560Z ##[debug]DEFAULTKEYCHAINPASSWORD=null
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5582810Z ##[debug]P12=/Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/13/s
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5603950Z ##[debug]P12PWD=null
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5625110Z ##[debug]IOSSIGNINGIDENTITY=null
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5645720Z ##[debug]PROVPROFILEUUID=null
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5667270Z ##[debug]PROVPROFILE=/Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/13/s
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5693190Z ##[debug]REMOVEPROFILE=false
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5714540Z ##[debug]ANTBUILD=false
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5735860Z ##[debug]KEYSTOREFILE=/Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/13/s
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5757280Z ##[debug]KEYSTOREPASS=null
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5778920Z ##[debug]KEYSTOREALIAS=null
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5800080Z ##[debug]KEYPASS=null
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5821180Z ##[debug]OUTPUTPATTERN=bin
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5842450Z ##[debug]CORDOVAARGS=null
2018-01-08T08:47:31.5863640Z ##[debug]CORDOVAVERSION=7.1.0
2018-01-08T08:47:31.7683300Z Input to determineIdentity: {"cwd":"/Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/13/s/dev-branch/src/Alcami.Web/cordova","unlockDefaultKeychain":false,"defaultKeychainPassword":"","p12":"/Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/13/s","p12pwd":""}
2018-01-08T08:47:31.7697670Z p12 not specified in task.
2018-01-08T08:47:31.7716980Z determineIdentity result {}
2018-01-08T08:47:31.7730320Z No explicit signing identity specified in task.
2018-01-08T08:47:31.7745530Z Input to determineProfile: {"cwd":"/Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/13/s/dev-branch/src/Alcami.Web/cordova","provProfileUuid":"","provProfilePath":"/Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/13/s","removeProfile":false}
2018-01-08T08:47:31.7760580Z determineProfile result {"uuid":""}
2018-01-08T08:47:31.7775940Z Module cache at /Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules
2018-01-08T08:47:32.4808290Z cordova@7.1.0 already installed.
2018-01-08T08:47:35.2355330Z Module cache at /Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules
2018-01-08T08:47:35.8792230Z cordova@7.1.0 already installed.
2018-01-08T08:47:36.0986510Z Adding support plugin.
2018-01-08T08:47:37.4049580Z { Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (The platform "android" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. android not supported.)
2018-01-08T08:47:37.4063840Z     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:163:17)
2018-01-08T08:47:37.4078380Z     at EventEmitter.module.exports.emit (/Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/7.1.0/node_modules/cordova-common/src/events.js:71:17)
2018-01-08T08:47:37.4094150Z     at Object.getPlatformApiFunction (/Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/7.1.0/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/util.js:500:20)
2018-01-08T08:47:37.4109090Z     at Object.getPlatformApi (/Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/7.1.0/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/platforms/platforms.js:55:25)
2018-01-08T08:47:37.4124680Z     at handleInstall (/Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/7.1.0/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:593:29)
2018-01-08T08:47:37.4139810Z     at /Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/7.1.0/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:357:28
2018-01-08T08:47:37.4154720Z     at _fulfilled (/Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/7.1.0/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
2018-01-08T08:47:37.4169100Z     at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/7.1.0/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
2018-01-08T08:47:37.4184670Z     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/7.1.0/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
2018-01-08T08:47:37.4200220Z     at /Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/7.1.0/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
2018-01-08T08:47:37.4215250Z   context: 'The platform "android" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. android not supported.' }
2018-01-08T08:47:37.4237540Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2018-01-08T08:47:37.4340660Z ##[error]Task failed
```

Comment: Do you use private build agent? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive (set system.debug variable to true)?  Can you build the project through command manually on your local machine?

Comment: No. I am using macos agent and yes the project is running fine on my local machine.

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive?

Comment: Find the link for logs : https://digitalmettle-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/p/piyush/ETCKi3pb94RAjLCGpfV81TYBPWxZlGt8Sj9GwFXl_pBhCw?e=P9rmfd

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new project?

Comment: Thanks @starian chen-MSFT for your support :) :) . I have resolved my issue. Actually I was using the wrong config.xml (which is for android not for ios).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have resolved my problem. Actually the problem was the config.xml. I was using the config.xml which was for android.

Comment: Didn't get u . Was that issue in config.xml file ?

Comment: @Anuj: Yes, the config file I was using, it was for android not for the iOS.

Comment: config file is mandatory for both .All configuration sets on that for android as well as ios. btw i did that with command npm install again

Comment: Are you facing the same problem?

Comment: What was the solution to this problem? I have the same error and as per the other people that have commented the config.xml file is used for both ios and android so your solution doesn't make much sense, what did you have to change in the config.xml file to get this to work?